# Why can't I set the language in numbro.js?

Tags: javascript

I cannot succeed setting the language in numbro, with language.min.js included. I'm using the CDN-include. What am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div id="number"></div>
```

**JS**

```
numbro.setLanguage("de-DE");
var number = numbro("1111111111").format({thousandSeparated: true});
document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = number;
```

The result should read 1.111.111.111 but it is 1,111,111,111.

When I step into the underlying method, the variable languages contains only "en-US", but numbro.allLanguages contains "de-DE". Somehow the initialization does fail...

http://jsfiddle.net/rj927ewm/

Answer (score 2):

As was explained to me [here](https://github.com/BenjaminVanRyseghem/numbro/issues/388), I missed to register the included languages with `numbro.registerLanguage(<locale>)`. For all languages you would do this:

```
Object.values(numbro.allLanguages).forEach(function(data) {
  numbro.registerLanguage(data);
})
```